# parsing command line output on Windows command line batch file

Tags: windows, parsing, batch-file, command-line

I have this command that scan a file and returns a summary.

For example on running this command

```
omsCmdLineUtil.exe process C:\test.exe Default
```

the result output is:

```
Ticket:[ 2214271306 ]

Process Details
---------------


File: [ C:\test.exe ]
   MD5: [ D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E ]
   SHA1: [ DA39A3EE5E6B4B0D3255BFEF95601890AFD80709 ]
   SHA256: [ E3B0C44298FC1C149AFBF4C8996FB92427AE41E4649B934CA495991B7852B855 ]
   File Size: [ 0 bytes ]
   File Type  Category: [ O ]
   File Type: [ - ]
   File Type Description: [ empty ]

[ Clean ] Ahnlab scan engine [ 1 ms ]
[ Clean ] ClamAV scan engine [ 1 ms ]
[ Clean ] BitDefender scan engine [ 1 ms ]
[ Clean ] Avira scan engine [ 1 ms ]
[ Clean ] Quick Heal scan engine [ 1 ms ]
[ Clean ] ThreatTrack scan engine [ 1 ms ]
[ Clean ] ESET scan engine [ 1 ms ]
[ Clean ] Total Defense scan engine [ 1 ms ]

Scan Completion
---------------
        [ Clean ]
        Ticket: [ 2214271306 ]
        File path: C:\test.exe
        Scan time: 1 ms [12/20/2015 13:00:06:791]


Process Completion
------------------
        Ticket: [ 2214271306 ]
        User agent: Default
        Profile: Default
        Result: [ Allowed ]
        File processed: C:\test.exe
```

I want to create a batch file that parses this result by searching for the output line `Result:`, check if it's `[ Allowed ]` or `[ Blocked ]` and return `0` for `allowed` and `1` for `blocked`.

I tried something like this, but its not really working:

```
omsCmdLineUtil.exe process C:\test.exe Default | set ts = findstr /C:"Result: [ Allowed ]"

if %ts% == "Result: [ Allowed ]" return 0
else return 1
```

Which modification on code is necessary to get the expected result?

Comment: basically, because there is no variable `%ts%`. You produced one with the Name `%ts %`. Be carefull with spaces in Batch.

Comment: Also, the variable you created is temporary because each side of the pipe is run in a child process. The variable disappears once the pipe is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no `return` in Batch. I think, you want `exit /b <errorlevel>`

```
omsCmdLineUtil.exe process C:\test.exe Default | find "Result: [ Allowed ]" >nul && Exit /b 0 || Exit /b 1
```

Instead of `Exit 0` you can of Course also use `set ts=0` and use that. Or use `echo` instead.

Some explanations:

`>nul` redirects the output to nirvana, keeping your screen clean.

`&&` acts as "If previous command was successfull, then..." (string was found)

`||` acts as "if previous command was not successfull, then...` (string was not found)

I prefer using `find` when possible because of it's simpler syntax, but of course `findstr /C:"Result: [ Allowed ]"`will also work

Comment: `exit` will also terminate the `cmd` instance the batch file is running in, whereas `exit /B` only terminates the batch file itself...

Comment: FIND already returns ERRORLEVEL of 0 for found and 1 for not found, so the conditional EXIT /B statements are redundant. You could simply issue a single EXIT /B (without specifying ERRORLEVEL) and the FIND result will be propagated.

Comment: @dbenham yes, but better be sure: something like `...||(timeout 5&exit /b)` may ruin it.

Comment: thank you for all the great answers, i have another sub-question. what if i want to find two lines in the output . is that also easily possible ? thanks

Comment: `findstr` is able to do that. See `findstr /?`